# Stopwords and stemming in Lucene demo

Tags: lucene, stop-words, stemming

I have two major questions about the Lucene Demo. Does the Lucene demo use stopwords before any modification?
What about stemming? If so, what stemmer does it use?

Answer (score 0):

Which demo are you referring to?

If it's [this one](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/demo/overview-summary.html#overview.description), then the answers are:

(a) **Stop words**: no, it does not. It uses the `StandardAnalyzer()` which does not use stop words when created with no arguments (but it can, if you choose to provide some).

(b) **Stemming**: no it does not use stemming - there are no stemming classes involved in the demo code, because there is no stemming used by the standard analyzer.

Take a look at the javadoc for the [`StandardAnalyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html). You will see the following:

> Filters StandardTokenizer with LowerCaseFilter and StopFilter, using a configurable list of stop words.

So, this tells you how your input documents are analyzed:

- Using the [`StanadardTokenizer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html), the rules for which you can read about [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/).
- Using the [`LowerCaseFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/LowerCaseFilter.html) - which works like you would expect.
- Using the [`StopFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopFilter.html) - for which you may or may not have provided any stop words.

Comment: Lucene 8.7.0 demo I mean.

Comment: The demo I linked to in my answer is the "official" Lucene 8.7.0 demo - so I assume that is the one you are referring to. All of the Lucene documentation links appear to be broken, at the moment - here is [another link to the same demo](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/master/lucene/demo/src/java/org/apache/lucene/demo) (this one is for the demo's source code).